# Access Spring boot application properties in docker compose file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have two application one application is for API another one is UI(UI is dependent on API_portal), I am not containerizing db.

docker_compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  ui_application:
    image: ui_app
    build:
      context: ./ui_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - admin_portal_app
  admin_portal_app:
    image: admin_portal
     build:
      context: ./admin_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs
```

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/*.war admin_portal.war
ENTRYPOINT [ "Java", "-jar", "admin_portal.war"]
Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/*.war ui_app.war
ENTRYPOINT [ "Java", "-jar", "ui_app.war"]

```
    application.properties(Admin Portal API)
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/test
    spring.datasource.username = xxx
    spring.datasource.password = xxx
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    server.port=8090
    logging.file=./logs/adminportal.log
```

I want to externalize all application properties in docker-compose file.please guide me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly , you want to inject spring properties through docker-compose.

You can leverage the env variables for the same.
Do the following :

1. Create a start up script and package this into the image.
2. Inside this script , put in your java start command like so

   `java \
     -Xmx$XMX_VALUE \
     -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=$MAX_METASPACE_SIZE \
     -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
     -XX:HeapDumpPath=$HEAP_DUMP_PATH \
     -Dspring.datasource.url=$DB_URI \
     -Dspring.datasource.username=$DB_USERNAME \
     -Dspring.datasource.password=$DB_PASSWORD  \
     -jar <your app.jar>`
3. Lastly inject the required variables through the docker compose :

   `admin_portal_app:
      image: admin_portal
      build:
       context: ./admin_app
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
      volumes:
       - ./logs:/logs
      environment:
       - DB_URI=<uri>
       - DB_USERNAME=<username>
       - DB_PASSWORD=<password>`

Comment: `java \
  -Xmx$XMX_VALUE \
  -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=$MAX_METASPACE_SIZE \
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
  -XX:HeapDumpPath=$HEAP_DUMP_PATH \
  -Dspring.datasource.url=$DB_URI \
  -Dspring.datasource.username=$DB_USERNAME \
  -Dspring.datasource.password=$DB_PASSWORD  \
  -jar <your app.jar>` i have to put in docker file and run it with Dockerfile FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine ADD target/.war admin_portal.war ENTRYPOINT [ "Java", "-jar", "admin_portal.war"] lets say i have 4 data sources so how do i add them

Comment: allowed.origin=8080 how do i externalize this property to docker-compose file

Comment: 1. create .env file in the same folder which contains docker-compose.yaml
2. update the file with `ALLOWED_ORGIN=8080`
in your docker-compose use the variable : 
`environment: `
`   - allowed.origin=${ALLOWED_ORIGIN}`

Read this for more details : https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/